# Making a new variable from multiplying another

Tags: multiplication

Here is the section of the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
def gbp():
gbpTo = int(input("Which currency are you converting into?"))
if gbpTo == "1":
    print("You are converting Pounds Sterling to Pounds Sterling... there is no conversion needed!")
elif gpbTo == "2":
    num = float(input("Please type in the amount of Pounds Sterling that you wish to convert into US Dollars")
    calc = num * 1.55
    calc = round(calc, 2)
    print(num + " Pounds Sterling in US Dollars is $", calc)
```

When I run it, it comes up with syntax error, highlighting `calc`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

One parenthesis is missing, the one that closes float().

```
...
num = float(input("Please type in the amount of Pounds Sterling that you wish to convert into US Dollars"))
...
```